# put a condition foreach laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'm looking for a solution inside a Laravel project.

```
            <div class="owl-carousel" id="listcarousel">
            @foreach ($property->images as $image)
                <div class="item"><img  src="{{ RvMedia::getImageUrl($image, null, false, RvMedia::getDefaultImage()) }}" class="showfullimg" rel="{{ $loop->index }}" alt="{{ $property->name }}"></div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

I need to put a condition in the foreach loop that outputs files with the jepg extension with the following tag:

```
 <div class="item"><img  src="{{ RvMedia::getImageUrl($image, null, false, RvMedia::getDefaultImage()) }}" class="showfullimg" rel="{{ $loop->index }}" alt="{{ $property->name }}"></div>
```

And files with mp4 extension with the following tag:

```
<div class="item"><video  src="{{ RvMedia::getImageUrl($image, null, false, RvMedia::getDefaultImage()) }}" class="showfullimg" rel="{{ $loop->index }}" alt="{{ $property->name }}"></video></div>
```

Yes, I save all movie and photo files on one table.

Comment: We keep our thumbs! Good luck! Ah... BTW what did you try? Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In your table add a field file extension in your table, with this field you can group your specific file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach($property->images as $image)
    <div class="item">
        @if(str_contains($property->name, '.jpeg'))
            <div class="item"><img  src="{{ RvMedia::getImageUrl($image, null, false, RvMedia::getDefaultImage()) }}" class="showfullimg" rel="{{ $loop->index }}" alt="{{ $property->name }}"></div>
        @else
            <div class="item"><video  src="{{ RvMedia::getImageUrl($image, null, false, RvMedia::getDefaultImage()) }}" class="showfullimg" rel="{{ $loop->index }}" alt="{{ $property->name }}"></video></div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

It checks your $property->name, if its has '.jpeg' string then shows img tag. Else, shows video tag.